# Xorg.conf ignores synaptics settings for scroll direction

Tags: drivers, xorg, mouse, touchpad, synaptics

Because of poorly functioning touchpad I wanted to provide more detailed configuration for it using xorg.conf.

So I create a new xorg configuration file by copying default configuration file using `cp /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics-mod.conf`.

I reboot and check current values for two parameters (nothing should have changed now).

```
pca:~$ synclient -l | grep 'VertScrollDelta\|EmulateTwoFingerMinZ'
    EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 282
    VertScrollDelta         = 24
```

So far everything seems OK, there are just some default values in there.

---

---

Now I would like to change these two parameters.

So i open created file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics-mod.conf` and modify this section

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "touchpad catchall"
    Driver "synaptics"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    #Option "EmulateTwoFingerMinZ" "13"
    #Option "VertScrollDelta" "17"
EndSection
```

by adding two options that are commented out in the snippet.

I reboot and get values

```
pca:~$ synclient -l | grep      'VertScrollDelta\|EmulateTwoFingerMinZ'
    EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 13
    VertScrollDelta         = 24
```

So `EmulateTwoFingerMinZ` was modified as expected. But for whatever reason `VertScrollDelta` remains the same.

What could be behind this madness?

I am using standard `ubuntu`, `gnome` and `synclient VertScrollDelta=17` works fine.

Comment: Do you still have this issue with libinput ?